# Can I get children on same model where parent belongs to another model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a model where child models have this relationship with parent:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id', 'unique_id')->orderBy('id', 'asc');
}
```

My table looks like this:

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('type');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('unique_id');
        $table->bigInteger('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('order')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unique(['unique_id', 'project_id'], 'abcd')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

unique_id field is only unique per project, which is why I did this: `$table->unique(['unique_id', 'project_id'], 'abcd')->unsigned();`

However the relationship defined earlier fails if I have 2 projects, 2 parents belonging to separate projects and two child models belonging to the parents.

```
Project 1
Project 2

Model 1
    uniqueId: 123
    projectID: 1

Model 2
    uniqueId: 1234
    parentId: 123
    projectId: 1


Model 3
    uniqueId: 123
    projectID: 2

Model 4
    uniqueId: 1234
    parentId: 123
    projectId: 2
```

When I load the edit page for project 1, I see Model 1 with two child models: Model 2 and Model 3

How can I in the definition of children relationship define that relationship is only valid if they belong to the same project?

I have tried this instead

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id', 'unique_id')->where('project_id', $this->project_id)->orderBy('id', 'asc');
}
```

But it failed, I did `dump($this->project_id)` and that prints null. So `project_id` is not available at that point it seems and I can't restrict what is being returned?

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: what will be printed if you dump `this`? And does it work if you hardcode the value?

Comment: yes it worked nice if I put parent_id to 1, then it returned stuff. I guess $this->parent_id is null when i printed it because sql has not been executed yet and value is then null

Comment: who to you load your childen? With `with` or with `load`? Something like this could work: `MyModel::find(1)->load('children');`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a problem avoidable with a proper normalized table, my personal suggestion is that you take parent_id and unique_id into a different model so you dont have rows with nulls in parent_id